# Tab design is broken on profile page on iPadOS

Tags: bug, design, tabs, ios

I’ve been using SE sites for a long time from my iPad on Chrome (or Safari, since mobile Chrome is [no longer supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/browser-support) officially), and recently I noticed that the tab design on the profile page became broken:

> [image: Tabs on the profile page]